# Create a web UI to edit send mail's aliases file

Tags: java, tomcat, sendmail

I want to make an web editor to edit send mail aliases file. When user edits and hits save button the aliases file should get saved and send mail should use this new aliases thereon.

As aliases file of send mail requires root access to edit tomcat does not have sufficient rights to edit aliases file.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a local file owned by tomcat and then have a 'root' cron job which checks for changes in this local file and adds them to you alias file